# Yarn ignore-engines for specific packages

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

When installing dependencies using yarn, one package (newrelic) gives the following error:

```
newrelic@5.6.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.0.0 <11.0.0". Got "11.13.0"
```

The only workaround to this I could find is to run

```
yarn install --ignore-engines
```

However, this would ignore engine mismatch across packages. Is there any way to ignore it only for a specific package?

Comment: Would also like this, it is kind of a large hammer to ignore all engines when just one package has an engine you don't care about

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be a way to provide package-specific flags on the install command.

However, you can try adding the problematic packages with the flag and followup with a normal install afterwards.

```
yarn add <problematic packages> --ignore-engines
yarn install
```

By default, unless `--force` is provided as a flag to `yarn install`, packages that already are installed will not be fetched again.